# Waring problem for binomial coefficients (generalization of Gauss' Eureka Theorem)

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Is there a number k such that every natural number can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{a_i}{3}$ for some natural numbers $a_i$'s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Watson's nice paper "Sums of eight values of a cubic polynomial" (http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-27/2/217.full.pdf) shows that we may take $k = 8$.

Answer (score 8):

It is an old [conjecture of Pollock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollock%27s_conjectures) that every positive integer is the sum of at most five tetrahedral numbers. In fact it is conjectured that all positive integers except for a finite list of 241 numbers, [A000797](http://oeis.org/A000797), are the sum of $4$ tetrahedral numbers.

Comment: Gjergji: Is it known that there exists a finite number $k$ such that each number is a sum of $k$ tetrahedral numbers?

Comment: Yes, that's known for any polynomial that takes integer values.

Comment: The earliest reference I found is: Kamke, E.. "Verallgemeinerungen des Waring-Hilbertschen Satzes." Mathematische Annalen 83 (1921): 85-112

Comment: As Gjergji has pointed out, this is a consequence of a general theorem of Kamke. A modern reference is Nathanson's Elementary methods in Number Theory; see Chapter 11, especially Theorems 11.10 and 11.12.

Answer (score 2):

In more general case this problem was studied by Nechaev, see

1. [On the question of representing natural numbers by a~sum of terms of the form $x(x+1)\ldots (x+n-1)/n!$](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=tm&paperid=2571&option_lang=eng)
2. [On the representation of natural numbers as a sum of terms of the form $x(x+1)\ldots (x+n-1)/n!$](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=3481&option_lang=eng)