# Binomial Waring Problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Let polynomial $\ P\in\mathbb R[X]\ $ be such that $\ \exists_{x\in\mathbb N} P(x)=1\ $ and
$\ P(x)\in\mathbb Z\ $ for every $\ x\in\mathbb Z.$

Let $\ m\in\mathbb N. $ Let's define the P-Waring numbers in a standard way:

$\quad g_P(m)\ $ is the minimal natural number $\ n\in\mathbb N\ $ such that
every natural number $\ x\ge m\ $ is a sum of at the most $\ n\ $ values
$\ P(k)\ $ for natural arguments $\ k.$

Then, let
$$ g_P\ := \ g_P(1) $$
and finally let
$$ G_P\ :=\ \min(g_P(m):\ m\in \mathbb N). $$

In particular, when $\ p(X)\ :=\ X^n\ $ we get the standard Waring number $\ g_n\ $ and $\ G_n.$

*Binomial coefficent* polynomials $\ P(X):=\binom Xn\ $ seem to fit the Waring problem better than $\ X^n; $ Gauss was very happy to prove

$$ g_{\binom X2}\ =\ 3 $$

**Question:** \nbsp; What is known or what can you prove about numbers
$\ g_{\binom Xn} $ and $\ G_{\binom Xn}.$

I guess, it should be relatively simple to show that

$$ \forall_{n\in\mathbb N}\quad g_{\binom Xn} <\ g_n. $$

Comment: Pollock conjectured, in 1850, that every positive integer is a sum of at most five tetrahedral numbers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollock%27s_conjectures which links to https://oeis.org/A000797

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thank you -- it wouldn't hurt to post your comment as a (partial?) Answer.

Comment: It's already posted to an older, closely related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196224/waring-problem-for-binomial-coefficients-generalization-of-gauss-eureka-theore Also related: https://alexey.im/papers/waring's-problem-final-project-mat403.pdf

Comment: @GerryMyerson -- thank you again. Thus, this second link could do as an Answer (I am not pressing but just suggesting).